# Question about deck of cards using OOP python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

This is the current code:

```
import random

class Cards():
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit.upper()))


class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        suits = ['Spades', 'Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']

        for suit in suits:
            for value in range(1,14):
                self.cards.append(Cards(value,suit))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()

    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
            rand = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[rand] = self.cards[rand], self.cards[i]

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()


deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

deck.draw().show()
```

The OOP part still confuses me, so excuse my elementary question but how come I can do `deck.draw().show()` but not `deck.shuffle().draw().show()`?

What I mean is that when I keep `deck.shuffle()` AND THEN do `deck.draw().show()` it returns to me random cards. So what if I just wanted to do deck.shuffle().draw().show()? Why does it give me an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\deckofcards.py", line 40, in <module>
    deck.shuffle().draw().show()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'
PS C:\Users\learning_log>
```

Comment: Think about what *shuffle returns*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that behaviour with one small change:

```
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
            rand = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[rand] = self.cards[rand], self.cards[i]
        return self # <- return a reference to the deck itself
```

Demonstration:

```
In [95]: deck.shuffle().draw().show()
8 of HEARTS
```

The reason you were getting that error is that you weren't `return`ing anything from `shuffle()`.

Comment: Thank you! Also, should I have done this using inheritance? I followed this code from someone on youtube and I am in the processing of learning it, but in my book they use inheritance for certain things. Surely, I thought a card game would be a nice candidate for using inheritance but it seems like he didn't use it here

Comment: Inheritance here could be necessary if, for example, you had a specialised deck of cards; say, for Pinochle which uses a 48-card deck. You could inherit all the functionality from your Deck class and then restrict the type of cards in the Pinochle subclass.

Comment: Inheritance is *never* necessary. Sometimes it is useful. Often it is not.

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `deck.shuffle().draw().show()` because as the error says, deck.shuffle() is a nonetype, that means it has no value, because `shuffle()` does some stuff, it doesn't return anything so you are esentially doing 'nothing'.draw().show(). To solve it you could return something, just like other answer said you could return a reference to the deck.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please consider providing a code snippet with the problem fixed, and please make sure your answers comply with Stack overflow community guidelines.